# How to make StaggeredGridLayoutManager rtl?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` start to arrange items from right side to left side(not from bottom to top which is achieved by setting `reverseLayout` to `true`)

I set the `layoutDirection` of recyclerview to rtl but it didn't work. I also tried to extend its behavior and override its `isLayoutRtl()` method but I could not because that method's `access-modifer` is `package` and I could not override it.

Is there any way to this? Thanks.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: @HadiAhmadi Not yet.